# Is there an environment variable or way to get custom task directory in VSO Build?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, azure-devops, jshint, azure-pipelines

So I'm trying to get the custom build task directory name from powershell when executing a custom build task.

The purpose is that I want [jshint](http://jshint.com/) to run on build time, and I've got it doing so, but the .jshintignore file needs to know a *relative* path to exclude files or folders.

So I need be able to get that path at runtime in order to know how many "../" to add on to the excluded files for the [minmatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) engine, which is what jshint uses, to match them.

I can, of course, hard code it, but that's really not what I'd prefer to do.

Comment: Hi Ryan, if I understand you correctly you are simply trying to ignore all of the other folders?  Can't you simply tell JSHint to only look under the Build.SourcesDirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the **Agent.HomeDirectory** variable.

> Agent.HomeDirectory | AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY | The directory the agent is
>   installed into. This contains the agent bits

The tasks folder will be $(Agent.HomeDirectory)\tasks(TaskFolder)\

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect. I love the new scriptable cross-platform build engine btw.